# Sending Bulk SMS using smart bro plug in vb.net

Tags: sms, sender

I am developing a sms bulk sender using smart bro plug in modem.

when I am sending, it gives an error of Message sending failed. This is my code.

```
   With Serialport1
    .Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    .Write(AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    .Write("AT+CMGS=1" & Chr(34) & txtNumber.Text & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
    .Write(RichTextBox.text & Chr(26))
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    MsgBox(rcvdata.ToString)
```

When I use Putty to check the connection of the modem; these are the results

```
    AT
    ok

    AT+CMGF=1
    Ok

 'when I tried

    AT+CMGS="+639970850099"
    Error
```

Requesting someone who can help me.

Thank you and keep safe.

Answer (score 0):

.Write("AT+CMGS=1" & Chr(34) & txtNumber.Text & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)

No 1 sa AT+CMGS=

Should be
.Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & txtNumber.Text & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)